# Library Corrupt Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, visual-c++-6

I have written a program from a book on visual c++. I am using its older version 6.0 but visual `c++ 6.0` gives me the following error

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\LIB\libcpd.lib : 
    fatal error LNK1127: library is corrupt
Error executing link.exe."
```

Can any one can explain this or offer any solution?

Comment: I have added the missing punctuation and formatting, and corrected the spelling. This was a bad question, next time, please try harder.

Comment: As has been suggested, I recommend obtaining a newer version of Visual Studio. It sounds to me like something is corrupted with your installation of VC 6 or your project's settings. There's little point in trying to fix it when you can download the latest version for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).

Answer (score 1):

When you start to program C++ guided by a book, choose anything except something that needs this old compiler. The newer Visual Studio Express versions can be downloaded and use without any cost.

With your VC++ 6.0 approach you would be out-of-date immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the file got corrupted.  Get your machine stable again, focus on the hard drive.  Ask questions about that at superuser.com.  Then reinstall VS6.  If the book gives sample code that works on VS6 then you really should consider upgrading the book.

Comment: Or don't bother installing VC6 ever again. Go for VC2010 instead.